# unable to get the value in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

i am trying to get the value in `UITableViewCell` but unable to get!!
here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

         tbcell.text = aBook.Name;
return cell;
}
```

when i print this value then its showing in gdb and also when i use `UITextField` instead of `cell` then it also shows the values.. i dont know whats happening!!
help.

Comment: I don't really get your question.. Do you want the cell's text to be aBook.Name? In that case, why do you call it tbcell? Also, if tbcell is a custom cell, you'll need: `[tbcell.labelName setText:abook.Name];`

Comment: tbcell is object of UITableViewCell that i have declared in .h. I used your's line of code and giving error "labelName is not something structure or union.

Comment: The line of code should only be used if your using a custom cell named tbcell, which has a label on it, connected through an IBOutlet called "labelName". I still don't know what kind of object tbcell really is, but I have to concur with underneath answers. Try `cell.text = aBook.Name;` Else, tell me how you declared tbcell?

Comment: issue get solved . i was deploying in iphone simulator 2.1.2 thats why the line of code "cell.text = aBook.Name; " was not working! then i switched to simulator 3.1.2 and all is working well!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not even sure what you're asking, but i'll try anyway as i see some weird stuff right away.

I'd replace

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

with

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

You were creating your cells with a frame with 0 values, i might be missing something if you're doing it on purpose though.

Also the ["text"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW56) property of UITableViewCell is deprecated, use cell.textLabel.text instead

Answer (score 0):

why are you using `tbcell.text = aBook.Name;` i think it `cell.textLabel.text = aBook.Name;`

Comment: displaying error "textLabel is not comething structure or union!"

Comment: `static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    
  
    cell.textLabel.text = aBook.Name;
    
    return cell;` will this work?

Comment: the code provided by zaky german is working!! thanks for help!1

Comment: is `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` this method being called did you put the break point and checked? and what is abook.name can you please tell that